# wget on Windows silent

Tags: windows, batch-file, wget

I am trying to figure out a way that I can use a Windows bat file and hopefully wget to simply go to a url, so the url can catch the activity and then process further information from there. Ideally, it would just be a bat file, that executes and doesn't have to open up a browser window at all. I can't seem to find the right combination of triggers to make it execute as such.

PS: not looking to install anything else, but just allow this to work as ideally needed.

**EDIT**:

So another alternative may to be use something like the start command within a bat file, but I'd like to see if I could get that to execute silently.  As an example:

```
start "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe http://url.com/dark.html
```

Every night, I double click that bat file and it opens a tab in my browser and displays a page with a blank screen for me. Then I just F11 it, and go to bed. But that works, and what I don't like about it, is the dependency of having a certain browser install for each machine. I'd rather just use something that is on all windows machines to get this to work. So I thought something like wget would be by default on Windows computers, that I could tap and use.

Comment: What do you want to do?  Your question isn't clear on that.

Comment: Basically take a unique identifying url, have it in the bat file and when the bat file is executed, it notifies that url, which then triggers a serious of events. For example: http://www.domain.com/notify.php?id=12345 - The bat file gets executed by a 3rd party software, the bat hits that url, that url then responds based on the id

Comment: Wget downloads a web page, or file.   Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Well, if I use wget, I can then use the php script to $_GET the id. I basically just need the bat file to be able to touch the url specified somehow. Either using wget or some other bat file magic.

Comment: Example of the flow wanted: 3rd party software -> create mp3 -> execute bat file -> touch specified url with an id -> page at url then is triggered to do further processing. The rest works - just the touching of the url is what I'd like to get accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
wget -O "%temp%\temphtml.tmp" -q "http://www.domain.com/notify.php?id=12345"
del "%temp%\temphtml.tmp"
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. I've modified the url to the one I have, and then I have a php script that catches any $_GET variables and writes them to a text file. Nothing is being written when I execute the bat file.

Comment: The batch file writes the output in the temp folder in a file called `temphtml.tmp` and which it then deletes.

Comment: You missed what I said. When the bat file is executed, it should "touch" the url that I have defined. That url is a php file that catches all $_GET's from it and writes it to a file on the server. Not the local stuff. By doing that, I can see if the file on the server has been written to and catches the id=xx when the bat file executes. Right now - it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to rely on a *certain* browser, you can use a *default* browser:

```
START "" "http://your.url.com/"
```